# pick up spawn hindering artifacts on temple run?

Tags: temple-run-2

Does increasing the pickup spawn passive ability make it harder for artifacts to appear?
This seems quite likely to me.

Answer (score 2):

The pickup spawn increase makes more items you jump for appear, and my understanding is that a fixed fraction of those are chests with artifacts.  So thus you would see more artifacts on average with the pickup spawn increased, not fewer.